# Assigning unarchived object to a different object works, why/how?

Tags: objective-c, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

Assigning an archived dictionary object but unarchived and assigned to an array does not seem to produce an exception and the logged out data from the array is that of the dictionary and not in array format at all if it was possible to assign to a different return type, kinda link casting but instead your unarchiving and assigning directly. Why does this work? if anyone can explain it much more deeply it would bring to light a better understanding of the unarchiving process and the way it works.

```
     NSDictionary *glossary = @{
                               @"Abstract class": @"some class",
                               @"Adopt": @"borrow",
                               @"archiving": @"Storing an object for later use"
                               };
    if([NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:glossary toFile:@"propertyList2.plist"] == YES)
        NSLog(@"Archive success");
     else
        NSLog(@"Archive unsuccessfull");

    NSArray *unArchiving = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"propertyList2.plist"];
    NSLog(@"%@", unArchiving); 

       //for (NSString *obj in unArchiving) {
       //  NSLog(@"%@: %@", obj,unArchiving[obj]);
       //   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Objective-C!  Due to the dynamism of the language, the type of an object reference (AKA variable) really only matters at compile time.  At runtime, what the object *is* matters; what you thought it aught to be when you wrote the code doesn't.

The reason your code for unarchiving works is because the `for (X x in Y)` syntax is identical for arrays and dictionaries.  Similarly, the indexing syntax (`a[x]`) is identical.  All of that is handled at runtime, based on the type of the collection being iterated.  As long as the semantics are the same, your code will run without error.  Obviously, the moment you try to treat that dictionary as an array (e.g. refer to `.lastObject`) it will blow up.